# \documentclass{tikz-qtree} Error Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands

Tags: errors, tikz-qtree

Probably got some obvious error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} % <- this wont work

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
Latex Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
```

on several editors whatsoever.

Got `2013.20140215-1 texlive-pictures` installed.
Adding `\usepackage{tikz}` doesn't help.

Probably I am missing something obvious.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. `\usepackage{tikz-qtree}`. It is a package not a class. Your document can have only one class but many packages!

Comment: The posted document runs without error.  If you get an error from that post the full log.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The original had `\documentclass{tikz-qtree}` but it is edited away within the 5 mins so no longer makes sense.

Comment: @cfr my guess would be OP has while editing saved a document as tikz-qtree.sty so gets the error but would need to see the log...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is almost certainly correct, since `tikz-qtree` is a wrapper for `tikz-qtree.tex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, you had

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{tikz-qtree}
...
```

A LaTeX document can only have one *class* as the error says. But you can also load *packages* to extend the functionality of the class. `tikz-qtree` is not a document class at all: it is a package. So, you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
...
```

## EDIT

After correcting the problem above, you continued to report the same error. This was somewhat puzzling but AlanMunn held the key to this mystery.

As explained by AlanMunn in comments, the package `tikz-qtree` loads a code file named `tikz-qtree.tex`. Because your document was itself called `tikz-qtree.tex`, LaTeX tried to read the document a second time when the package called the code file.

This happens because files in the current directory take precedence over those elsewhere, so LaTeX read your document `tikz-qtree.tex` rather than the code file `tikz-qtree.tex`.

Hence, it really did get two `\documentclass` commands as input - they just both happened to be from the single instance in your document.

I don't know if there is a moral to this story other than that AlanMunn knows everything there is to know about packages which draw trees, but at least it dispels the mystery.

Comment: Yes, I am just unsure why this produces that kind of error and how to fix this, because I'd like to use that package

Comment: @sams2 Originally, you had 2 `\documentclass` commands. That caused that error. You shouldn't get that error now you've changed the second, `tikz-qtree`, one to `\usepackage`.

Comment: Even <code> \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\end{document} </code> produces the same error

Comment: @sams2 It shouldn't. It doesn't for me. As David says, if it does for you, we need the log.

Comment: logfile http://pastebin.com/zCccKxfP

Comment: @sam2 The subsequent problem arose because your test file was named `tikz-qtree.tex` which is also the name of the code file that the `tikz-qtree` package uses. This is not something you could have easily forseen.

Comment: @AlanMunn You should answer but you can't. Should this be reopened? Or would you object if I added that information to my answer?

Comment: @cfr Just add it to your answer. I've encountered this problem before, and the log posted by the OP confirms it. But David had already suggested it too.  There's no need for a separate answer, and in some sense it's a very peculiarly local problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, his suggestion was that the document was saved as `.sty` which is a bit different. The `.tex` complication is rather less obvious ;).

Comment: You're right.  I read his comment too fast.