# Mysterious "Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands."

Tags: errors

The LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
zzz
\end{document}
```

causes in latex and pdflatex the mysterious error "Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands." Why??? **Not** actually **two** \documentclass like in the (original) question [\documentclass{tikz-qtree} Error Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251196/documentclasstikz-qtree-error-two-documentclass-or-documentstyle-commands).

Probably irrelevant, but I'm using texlive (2018 version) in a Debian system.

The .log as asked by moewe: https://pastebin.com/BGcHs3Rz.

Answering other comment: the filename is psttest.tex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For me the code works fine (as it should)... I'm also using TeXLive 2018, so I guess there is something else causing that problem. The error message should show in which line the problem happened. Can you show us the log, please?

Comment: Can you share the full `.log` file of  the LaTeX run on that file? If it is too long to be shared here, you can upload it to a text-sharing website like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, then the concrete compiler can be relevant... Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT call your document article.tex

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment. But with either compiler (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex`) it works (modulo `pstricks` complaining for `pdftex` and `luatex`).

Comment: To expand on Johannes' comment: Errors like this can occur if you have a `.tex` file with same base name as a file that belongs to a package or the class your document loads in the directory of your `.tex` file. The way LaTeX looks for package and class files means that files with the same base name from the working directory are given preference over installed package files. So if you call your document `article.tex` or `pstricks.tex` (or any other name that is already "taken" by a file related to a package you load), TeX tries to load the wrong file and may end up with two `\documentclass`es

Comment: In situations like this a look at the `.log` file should tell us which file is problematic. And even if this was not the cause of the error, the `.log` file can give us vital information about what went wrong because it will contain the full error message with line numbers.

Comment: @Johannes_B, isn't. Edited.

Comment: @moewe, edited to add the .log file.

Comment: As Johannes guessed: You have a file called `pstricks.tex` in the same folder as this file. But `pstricks` is the name of a package you load. TeX picks up the wrong file and chaos ensues. Rename `pstricks.tex` and you should be good.

Comment: @moewe, true. Is a previous (big) testfile. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crucial piece of information to understand this error is the line in the `.log` before the actual error message starts. It reads

```
(./pstricks.tex

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass[12pt]{
                         article}
?
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass[12pt]{
                         article}
The document may only declare one class.
```

The `(./pstricks.tex` means that TeX has opened a file called `./pstricks.tex` (i.e. a file in the same directory as your main TeX file called `pstricks.tex`). As soon as that file is loaded the error occurs in the `\documentclass` in line 1.

A part of the code of the package `pstricks` lives in a file called `pstricks.tex` and that file is loaded by the package. (`pstricks.sty` has the line `\input{pstricks}%`, which reads `pstricks.tex`.)

The way TeX loads files means that files in your current working directory are given preference over files installed by your TeX distribution. In general that is a very useful feature because you can easily override some things locally without changing system files.

But in this case that means that a totally unrelated file called `pstricks.tex` in the document directory is loaded instead of the package code in `pstricks.tex`.

The easiest way to avoid that is by renaming your local file to something other than `pstricks.tex`. In general you should avoid giving files the same name as a class or package, but you can never be entirely sure which names are problematic as packages could load additional `.tex` files with different names. The only way to be sure is by checking the `.log` thoroughly if similar issues occur.

Note that the error might have been much more cryptic and might have occurred at a different stage if your `pstricks.tex` had not contained a `\documentclass`, for example if it had been only a chapter of your paper that you load in a bigger document with `\input` or `\include`.

---

This is what [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) hinted at [in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480682/mysterious-two-documentclass-or-documentstyle-commands/480723#comment1214726_480682)

> Do NOT call your document article.tex

Though, incidentally, `acrticle.tex` would have probably been fine, since `article.cls` does not attempt to load `article.tex`.

A similar issue was discussed a few days ago in the German goLaTeX forum https://golatex.de/markdown-in-latex-einbinden-t21651.html where the issue appeared with the `markdown` package, which loads `markdown.tex`, when a user called their document `Markdown.tex` (on a Windows system, which is case insensitive).

Comment: Similarly, I had a document named keyval.tex and got the error when trying to compile another document (in the same folder) which was using `standalone` class: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350866/latex-error-two-documentclass-or-documentstyle-commands